# Update Check with PHP

Tags: php

I'm working on an update system that checks a remote file string

```
$local = simplexml_load_file(root_p.'/version.xml');
$remote = simplexml_load_file("mygithuburltoblob/version.xml");
if($local->build == $remote->build) {
} else {
    echo "Version ".$remote->version." Available now";
}
```

But even if the build numbers match it still returns that the update is available. Does anyone know why that would be?
(Yes root_p is already defined, the problem isn't loading and retrieving the values)
Remote Var Dump

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#12 (6) { ["title"]=> string(11) "Loopy Cubix" ["author"]=> string(12) "Morgan Green" ["version"]=> string(3) "1.0" ["build"]=> string(4) "1111" ["type"]=> string(5) "Alpha" ["feed"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#15 (0) { } }
```

Local Var Dump

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#11 (6) { ["title"]=> string(24) "Looped Cubix Pre Release" ["author"]=> string(12) "Morgan Green" ["version"]=> string(3) "1.0" ["build"]=> string(4) "1111" ["type"]=> string(6) "Closed" ["feed"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#15 (0) { } }
```

[image]

On the top of the page is my output from

```
                <?php
                $local = simplexml_load_file(root_p.'/version.xml');
                $remote = simplexml_load_file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Doxramos/Invontrol/master/version.xml");

                echo "Local: ". gettype($local->build);
                foreach($local->build as $build) {
                    echo $build. "<br />";
                }
                echo "Remote: ". gettype($remote->build);
                foreach($remote->build as $build) {
                    echo $build. "<br />";
                }
```

Shows both as an object with the same value.

Comment: There's no way we can now without seeing the xml or var_dumps of `$local` and `$remote`

Comment: @JohnConde Added the Variable dump.

Comment: Please provide code that starts with the XML instead, otherwise this can't be reproduced. The `var_dump()` output doesn't help here.

Comment: You'll need to do a little debugging there. What's the result of `var_dump($local->build == $remote->build)`? What's the result of `var_dump($local->build);` and `var_dump($remote->build);`? What about the variable types, do they match? Use [gettype()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) to check the variable's types.

Comment: @milz Added the variables types and outputs with a screenshot

Comment: @MorganGreen there's something weird there. `gettype($local->build)` is returning `object` where it should be a `string(4)` (as per your var_dump). Since both `$local->build` and `$remote->build` are objects, your if condition (`$local->build == $remote->build`) is comparing two objects, which is wrong. The condition should compare the build numbers (string).

Comment: Well I've fixed my original issue, but I'll look into that; for all I know my fix is a hacky workaround lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had to do with whitespace while parsing the XML data. I ended up fixing it by replacing

```
if($remote->build == $local->build) {
   }
else {
     //Output Update Information
}
```

with

```
$trimmed_local = trim($local->build);
$trimmed_remote = trim($remote->build);
```

And using the new variables as my comparison operators

```
if($trimmed_local == $trimmed_remote) {
 }
else {
   //Output Update Information
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see that oject is no equal, example of some compared elements:

```
["title"]=> string(11) "Loopy Cubix"

["title"]=> string(24) "Looped Cubix Pre Release"
```

Comment: That's just some tests to make sure that everything is being pulled together; Shouldn't it be comparing build if that's what I'm comparing?